# can anyone explain this completely random local IP address that appears on my network?

Tags: networking, router, ip, routing, dd-wrt

I have a DD-WRT router, and I am connected to a VPN.  My routers local IP is 192.168.11.1.  The VPN uses local address 10.10.0.6.  However there is this strange IP address 10.16.128.1 that is always there pointing to 255.255.255.255. What is this? If I reset the router, it still appears everytime. Anyone know?

[image]

Comment: Not 100%, but it might be an internal service socket that is used for something? But port 49 is typically associated with the Login Host Protocol TACACS+ .. so it might have something to do with your VPN ..? can you ping/nmap it (both from the router and an internal machine)?

Answer (score 4):

To 255.255.255.255:68 from an unfamiliar private IP address? Some device is likely broadcasting a DHCP Request, trying to renew an old lease it had from the previous network it was on.

Comment: Problem is I have never been on a network with such a network numbering scheme like that, as far as I know.  I am pretty familiar with each device on my network and don't see how I could simply be unaware of a random device.  Could one device broadcast a DHCP request from this and still be connected correctly using its correct IP? Meaning, can a device make 2 separate DHCP requests?

Answer (score 2):

To add to Spiff's reply:

You can gather more info on this, using the `arping command`. On Debian,

```
 sudo apt-get install iputils-arping
 sudo arping -f -c 1 -w 5  -I eth0 10.16.128.1
```

This will return you the MAC address of the component with IP address `10.16.128.1` You can then Google the MAC address, which will give you the maker of the NIC card. Often, this is enough to identify the culprit, but not always: as an example, Sony pcs do **not** necessarily have Sony NICs, and so on.

Comment: thanks but I don't have debian installed, is there any way to do something like this in WIndows 7, windows 8, or even Ubuntu?

Comment: @wardr Sorry, I should have probably said it explicitly: the commands above work perfectly in Ubuntu. As for Windows, read here, http://serverfault.com/questions/69890/is-there-any-way-to-arp-ping-on-windows